# Zoom GoogleMap to my location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a `SherlockFragmentActivity` that displays a [GoogleMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html) using [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/index). I want the map to zoom to my current location as soon as the fragment launches. I couldn't find such a method in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html). How to achieve this?

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ui_settings_demo);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    } 
}

private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    //How to zoom to my current location?


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this

```
CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(new LatLng(Lat,Lon))
        .zoom(zoom).build();

     map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position));
```

[Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you already know your location, that is not possible, as it will take time to find the location.

`setMyLocationEnabled(true)` merely allows the user to elect to center/zoom the map on their location. If you want to force it yourself, you will have to find the location yourself using `LocationManager` and set the camera position accordingly. Or combine the two, as I did in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Location). But, again, this will take some time.

Comment: I already know the location, I just removed some lines. Your code was helpful. I'll check it out. Thanks.